# Exporting a Mysql database to Access?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, phpmyadmin

I see there are multiple ways to do exports from mysql - the list phpmyadmin provides is given below:

I vote for the easiest way.  For example I can get a .sql file from the SQL option but I don't know where to go from there.  Likewise I can get a .php file but I don't know how to parse it from there into Access.  Thanks!

Codegen, CSV, CSV for MS Excel, MS Word 2000, latex, Media Wiki Table, Open Document Spreadsheet, Open Document Text, PDF, PHP Array, SQL, Texy text, Excel 97-2003, Excel 2007, XML, YAML

Export Working: PHP Array(.php), SQL (.sql)

Export Not Working: XML

Ambiguous: Excel 2007

Comment: Verified working? Why ask if you already have a working solution? SO isn't really a good place to have 'what is better' discussions...

Comment: From better to worse? Why oh why? Anyway, probably the best idea will be to export to Excel and then copy paste to Access.

Comment: Are you planning on doing this through code/script or through the UIs for a one-time thing?

Comment: @Chris - I imagine all the export functions 'work', whether they are in a format you can understand/read is not important.

Comment: Copy/Paste from Excel is a terrible solution. A proper import into Access would be much, much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would install a MySQL ODBC driver, create a DSN pointing to your MySQL database, then use the Access UI option to import from ODBC.  If you want a code approach, use the [DoCmd.TransferDatabase Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214131%28office.12%29.aspx)

Alternatively, you could create ODBC links in Access to your MySQL tables, then run "Make-Table" queries to create Access copies of those tables:

```
SELECT * INTO new_access_table
FROM mysql_linked_table;
```